# XQuery: Return value of attribute if it contains another spesific attribute

Tags: xquery

I want to return a result on all the books which contain the "databases" attribute in inside of "field".

```
for $e in //testbook[field="databases"]
return $e/title
```

Sample of the `.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-?>
<testbook>
<book>
<author> AuthorGuy </author>
<title> theBook</title>
<field> databases </field>
</book>
</testbook>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. `<title/>` and `<field/>` elements are contained in a `<book/>` element, and are not direct children of `<testbook/>`, fix the path expressions.
2. The `<field/>` tag contains the field wrapped in whitespace, use `contains($string, $needle)` instead of a simple comparison.

A working example:

```
let $document := document{<testbook>
<book>
<author> AuthorGuy </author>
<title> theBook</title>
<field> databases </field>
</book>
</testbook>}

for $e in $document//testbook[contains(book/field, "databases")]
return $e/book/title
```

Comment: I wasnt aware that the whitespace in <field/> would cause problems, I'll be aware of that in the future However I don't seem to get your working example to work. I'm not sure if it's due to my pure ignorance or Oxygen XML Editor not being my friend. Also would you are to elaborate what you by $needle, I'm not too familiar with the terminologies.

The idea being the simple comparison came from one of lecturer powerpoint slides which had a similar example which worked just fine with his .xml

"for $e in //employee[sex="F"]/name
return $e/lname".

This response is getting a little long.

Comment: Anyways, I really appreciate your input/help and futhermore if you've got more to correct :-)

Comment: For example, `contains("hello world", "world")` will return true as the "haystack" `hello world` contains the "needle" `world`. Whether whitespace matters or not is often subject of configuration. It is hard to provide further details on why it worked for your lecturer if you cannot provide the example (and example input!).